# Online Code Editor + File Hosting

Tags: css, cloud

I've been searching all over the Internet and am having trouble finding the following:

- An online code editor (with syntax highlighting, line numbers, etc.) that allows you to save the file in the "cloud" and access the raw file via a link.

I'm trying to use LESS from http://lesscss.org on my SquareSpace website, but it requires you to use a `<link href="..." />` tag instead of dropping the less directly in `<style>` tags in my site.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably belongs to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Mrchief - Haven't been active on SO in a while. Didn't realize there was a better site. Thanks for the suggestion :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I think I understand here. http://pastebin.com/ is an excellent website that I use. The code can be public or private and it has syntax highlighting for many languages.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks so much! I don't know why I didn't think of that before! I actually use GitHub gists and forgot they have the ability to grab the raw file as well.

Comment: Yeah GitHub is cool, quite like it, but the origional Pastebin is my fave :) Glad I could help.

Comment: FYI - For anyone reading this in regards to using LESS: this solution doesn't work since LESS actually loads the .less file via AJAX; which means it must be on the same server as your site due to the Cross Domain Policy. My solution: View Page Source, copy/paste it into an index.html file and have my `<link>` tag point at a local styles.less file. Hope this helps some future soul :-)

Answer (score 1):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) allows to write HTML, CSS and JavaScript and run the generated page.